# OnShareTargetActivated WindowsPhone 8.1 Target App crashes on debug

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to share Image to my Win 8.1 Phone App
When I select my app from share dialog.
The debugging in visual studio closes with error
Error:
Unable to start debugging 'U:\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppsLayouts\MyApp\MyApp.exe'
The object invoked has disconnected form client

When not debugging, in that case also the Target App Crashes

Any help to resolve this. I want to be able to debug my target app when activated through file sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to debug your share target app.

1. Set breakpoints in your target app.
2. Check ‘Do not launch but debug my code when it starts’ in project properties.
3. Launch your app in debugger – nothing happens.
4. Run share client app to share image, select your app from share dialog.
5. Debugger attaches and breaks on your breakpoint.

Reference **Debugging options** in [Deploying and debugging Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#debugging-options) aticle.
[image]